# Single bar width on a dynamic google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I've run into a problem creating a bar chart with google charts.
  Which is if you're creating a dynamic chart and there's a low amount of rows, the individual bars will be too thick.
  I understand that this question has been asked, the problem with the awnser that has been most frequent is that it does not work if there is only a single bar in the chart, that awnser is:
  to input `bar: {groupWidth: <value>}`

I have actually also found an awnser for if there is a single bar in the chart which is to insert an empty bar, so `groupWidth` works, but there are two problems with this solution, which are:
 -the bar will not be centered
 -and it will have an undefined title.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8puZK.png)

My question is, how can I set the maxWidth of a bar in google charts without using groupWidth.

also here is the code for my google chart

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chartCreate);

  function chartCreate() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Movimentos');

      data.addRows([[ "ola", 4 ]]);

    var options = {
      height: 405,
      width: 400,
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        fontSize: '24',
        bold: 'true',
        color: '#242354'
      },
      bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
      colors: ['#242354']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('graph'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two additional bars to center,
use a space for the first column to avoid `undefined`

```
[' ', null],
['ola', 4],
[' ', null]
```

otherwise, `bar.groupWidth` will not work
it's actually reported here as not working period, for *material* charts...
[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Movimentos');
  data.addRows([
    [' ', null],
    ['ola', 4],
    [' ', null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 405,
    width: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
      fontSize: '24',
      bold: 'true',
      color: '#242354'
    },
    bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
    colors: ['#242354']
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('graph'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```